# Scan and print strings

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

This first code scans three strings, and prints the strings out again. The first code works fine and prints out the strings, as can be seen in the first image link.

In the second code, the amount of strings must be variable. Thus I scan an integer k, and put this integer in the for loop. I would expect that this would have the same result when i would scan 2, but it does not have the same effect. Instead it only scans 2 strings, and prints out some signs before it prints out the string, as can be seen in the second image link. Does anyone have an explanantion for this?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxstring 100
#define maxc 10

int main()
{
char c, text[maxc][maxstring];
int i, j, n, k;

for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
{
    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!='\n'; i++)
    {
        text[j][i]=c;
    }
}
n=i;
    for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        putchar(text[j][i]);
    }


}

   return 0;
}
```

Second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxstring 100
#define maxc 10

int main()
{
char c, text[maxc][maxstring];
int i, j, n, k;

printf("Enter amount of strings:");
scanf("%d", &k);

for(j=0; j<=k; j++)
{
    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!='\n'; i++)
    {
        text[j][i]=c;
    }
}
n=i;
    for(j=0; j<=k; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        putchar(text[j][i]);
    }


}

   return 0;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: `c` must be `int`.

Comment: output for second code, is in image link above first code. Output image link for first code is under second code. Sorry for that..

Answer (score 1):

The second program reads the newline from entering `k` as the start of the first string, interpreting it as an empty string.  Because you didn't initialize `text`, and assume that all of the strings are the same length, garbage gets printed.

Also, your loop will read in `k`+1 strings; not sure if that is what you want or not.

Answer (score -1):

Allright, I get that the first code looks at the length of the first string(like the second code), and aussumes that the other strings have the same length. But why do i get a different result, when I scan the amount of strings(k) in the second code? I would expect that k only determence the amount of strings that the code scans.

Comment: This is, in no possible way, an answer.